# How to prove two matrices unitary equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A= $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      2&1&4\\
      0&1&2\\
0&0&1
    \end{array}
\right] $$
and B=$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      2&0&3\sqrt2\\
      1&1&\sqrt2\\
0&0&1
    \end{array}
\right] $$
Is there any method to find if they are matrix equivalent? Or we need to find a matrix S by trial and error such that $$S^*AS=B$$

Comment: First off, apply a permutation similarity to bring $B$ to the form
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&\sqrt{2}\\0&2& 3 \sqrt{2}\\ 0&0&1}
$$

Comment: It seems like the answer will be yes, which I find surprising

Comment: A common trick is to compare $tr(w(A,A^*))$ and $tr(w(B,B^*))$ where $w$ denotes a word on two letters.  So far, $tr(A^nA^{*n}) = tr(B^nB^{*n})$ up to $n=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess: try calculating $S^*BS$ with
$$
S = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&-1&0\\0&0&\sqrt{2}}
$$
The idea is that I begin by upper triangularizing $B$ to match the form of $A$, with $2$ as the first eigenvector.